# Пробую задать координаты точек с клавиатуры. При вызове функции f. Программа выдает два не относящихся к делу числа

Tags: c, массивы, структуры

Написал следующий код:

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

void f(struct point a)
{
     printf("x=%d",a.x);
     printf(" ");
     printf("y=%d",a.y);
     printf(" ");
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct point a[4];
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter x:");
        scanf("%d",&a[i].x);
        printf("Enter y:");
        scanf("%d",&a[i].y);
    }

    for (i=0; i<4; i++);
    {
        f(a[i]);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вы на верном пути :) Вроде все в пределах разумного. В чем же сама проблема?

Comment: Когда вызываю функцию f, программа выводит какой-то бред... Должна вывести введенные координаты точек, а выводит какие-то два числа. Вот так вызываю ее for (i=0; i<4; i++);
 {
 f(a[i]);
 }

Comment: **Именно так** - `for (i=0; i<4; i++); { f(a[i]); } `? С точкой с запятой после `for(...)`? Тогда это у вас 4 пустых итерации, и попытка вывести `a[4]`, которого нет...

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы в вопросе, и задавайте именно то, что нужно. Потому что в самом вопросе нет вопроса и нет проблемного кода - вопрос даже закрыть ответом нельзя, потому что на что я должен ответить?...

Comment: О святой паскаль! Сколько подводных камней))  Огромное спасибо, учитель)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, раз вопрос полный - то кроме ответа, что тут

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++);
{
    f(a[i]);
}
```

не нужна точка с запятой, я еще в качестве бонуса приведу свой вариант с пояснениями (я думаю, что следующим шагом неизбежно станет переменное количество точек):

```
typedef struct point_
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point;   // Больше не придется все время
           // тягать за собой слово struct

void f(point a)
{
    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n",a.x,a.y); // Так все в одной строке,
    // и вывод в одной строке с переходом на новую
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter number of points: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    point * a = malloc(n*sizeof(point));
    // Если компиляция в режиме С++ - то
    // point * a = (point*)malloc(n*sizeof(point));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Point %d -  x  y: ",i);  // Вводим сразу по два
        scanf("%d %d",&a[i].x,&a[i].y);  // числа в одной строке
    }

    puts("---");

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Point %d:  ",i);
        f(a[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

При работе это выглядит примерно так:

```
Enter number of points: 3
Point 0 -  x  y: 1 4
Point 1 -  x  y: 5 6
Point 2 -  x  y: 0 -2
---
Point 0:  x = 1, y = 4
Point 1:  x = 5, y = 6
Point 2:  x = 0, y = -2
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!!

Comment: Кое что в Вашем варианте не работает...( Error 3 error C2275: 'point' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: http://ideone.com/iCrPRa - см. здесь. Вы компилируете чем? VC++ 2015 берет запросто - и как C, и как C++ (в последнем случае нужно  только строку с malloc одну закомментировать, другую раскомментировать).

Comment: Я  в MS Visual Studio 2005 делаю)) переставил строку point * a = malloc(n*sizeof(point)); выше... сразу после определения i и n. Так там такое твориться начало...!) Просит ввести кол-во точек... а потом жесть) ошибки, предупреждения, спрашивает что то у меня вижуалка... в итоге ничего хорошего не выводит)

Comment: Все готово!!! Сделал в режиме ++...)) Пара глупых манипуляций с MSVS и вуаля) Попробую теперь это дело апроксимировать)) И да...) там еще getch(); в конце понадобился)

Comment: Ну, смотря откуда запускать... :) Я с консольными программами в окошке с Far работаю, так что для себя их вычищаю. Да и в ideone это тоже как-то не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
int n;
. . .

scanf("%d", &n);
a[i].x = n;
```